# Java на Текстовом редакторе Atom

Tags: java, atom

Как я могу подключить Java к Atom?
Недавно я начал изучать Java, а IDE Intellij IDEA пока слишком сложная для меня
в освоении. Вот я и нашел в Atom расширение ide-java, установил, но не могу понять как скомпилировать код. Все инструкции на английском, но даже с некоторыми манипуляциями (переводчик и т.д.) я все равно не смог найти ни кнопки компиляции, ни горячей клавиши.

Comment: предполагаю, что расширение предоставляет подсветку синтаксиса и автокомплит в лучшем случае, а компилировать Вам придётся в ручную: `javac HelloWorld.java`

Comment: `Features:
Auto completion; 
Code format; 
Diagnostics (errors & warnings); 
Document outline; 
Find references; 
Go to definition; 
Hover; 
Reference highlighting; ` про компиляцию и запуск тут ничего нет.